# Copied website to new IIS and I lost security

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, security, iis

First time copying my test database from "work" database to "live".  I used Visual Studio to design my website, my database is a SQL 2008 database, and I publish to IIS.

Security worked fine on my test website - the website asked for user id and password the first time I log on - using Windows authentication (Integrated Security =SSPI).  I copied my website to same server with Visual Studio, my SQL database to a new SQL Server, and published it to IIS on a new web server, keeping all the same settings. Now, with the new settings, any user can open the website - it does not ask for user id and password.  The website works correctly - the security just isn't working. Here's exactly how I copied:

I copied my Visual Studio project "timework - work copy" to "timework" on janetdev server.
I copied my SQL database "TimeSQL" on janetdev to "TimeSQL" on to the new SQL server.  I double checked all the user security to make sure that everything was the same on the new server.
I published the new VS project "timework" - keeping it Integrated Security =SSPI.
I went to the new IIS server and imported the new project into IIS.  I double checked all the settings in IIS (on old janetdev) to make sure that they were the same on the new server.

What could I be missing?  Why can anyone get into the new website??  The only thing I could think of is that everything (VS project, SQL database, and IIS) was on one server before.  Now, they are all on different servers.  One other thing - SQL was 2008 R2 on the test server, and it's 2008 on the new server.  Not sure if that could cause a problem.  I'm confused.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you saying that anybody can get in to your site, like there is no security? Or are saying that nobody can get in? If there are problems logging in there are likely some error messages???

Comment: Everyone can get into it.  I'm not seeing any error messages, but maybe I'm not looking in the correct spot.  Where should I look?  Everything else works great.

Comment: I don't know that anybody can help you with this one. There could be any number of things that are causing this. Poor security code, incorrect settings in the app or IIS...Without a LOT more details this is mostly going to be guesswork. I would start by looking at the code and figuring out how the security is supposed to work and then work forward from there to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS configuration such as authentication does not go with your web app while copying. You should use Web Deploy to create a deployment package and then install on the target server.